# Is there a complete and detailed description of what Migration Assistant copies over?

Tags: macos, backup, restore, migration

Does it copy all files in ~/Library ?  Including cache files and even things like Flash cookies?  What about user created files/folders in / ?

etc etc

Answer (score 3):

Migration Assistant is fairly well documented in http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4413 - basically if a newer or equivalent version of a file is not present, it gets moved by default.

In your case ~/Library is moved if you select that user - you can't deselect it like some other folders in the home folder.

Applications (which includes /Library/Application support as well as /Applications) move when that is selected.

Files in / only move if you choose other files. Everything goes AFAIK. Even ByHost preferences that no longer are used since the host has changed.

Answer (score 2):

The Migration Assistant will write to the logs, like every other application and service. Please see your logs for these details: `/Library/Logs/SystemMigration.log`

Comment: nothing there for me, on Mountain Lion - I could find it under `/private/var/log/system.log` tho, marked with **Sender** as `MigrateTool`

Answer (score 1):

One important file that appears **not** to move is /etc/hosts. Don't forget to manually copy it.